# Почему не работает обращение к элементу многомерного массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция getCellsOfSurface, на вход которой подаётся объект objSurface.
Структура входного объекта objSurface такова:

```
var pointsOfSurface=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];

var objSurface = {
   width: 2,
   height: 2,
   vertices: {}
};

objSurface.vertices=pointsOfSurface;
```

где свойство verteces представляет собой массив, элементами которого являются другие массивы, содержащие 4 числа. Например,
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], ... , [k, l, m, n]]
Если обратится к последнему числу элемента (т.е. номер 3) массива через консоль таким образом objSurface.vertices[204][3], то всё нормально. А в теле функции такой подход не работает.

```
function getCellsOfSurface(objSurface) {
    var result = [];
    var cell = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        radiation: 0
    };
    var averageRadiation;
    for (var j=1; j<objSurface.height; j++) {
        for (var i=1; i<objSurface.width; i++) {
            averageRadiation=objSurface.vertices[2][3];
            cell['x']=i;
            cell['y']=j;
            cell.radiation=averageRadiation;
            result.push(cell);
        };
    };
    return result;
};
```

я получаю ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
Почему? Даже выполнив тот же запрос к элементу в коде вне функции всё проходит нормально alert(objSurface.vertices[2][3]);

Функция getSerialNumber работает нормально и возвращает число.
Даже если в функции getCellsOfSurface убрать [3] и оставить просто

```
averageRadiation=objSurface.vertices[2];
```

то это тоже будет работать но мне возвратит массив [1,2,3,4]. Почему я не могу обратиться глубже?

И ещё они вопрос: в конце выполнения у всех cell.x и cell.y я получаю одно и то же значение 2 и 2. А должны быть возрастающие координаты. Здесь грешу на асинхронность.

Comment: "где свойство verteces представляет собой массив" : это `vertices: {}` - не массив. Где он, собственно говоря, заполняется 205-ю элементами?

Comment: @Igor до этого в коде происходит наполнение таким образом `objSurface.vertices=pointsOfSurface`; , где `pointsOfSurface` это массив пример которого я привел

Comment: "ещё они вопрос" - в коде создается только один объект `cell`

Comment: Постарайтесь создать минимальный пример кода, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: @Igor поправил значения и создал маленький рабочий пример, который должен воспроизвести проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Ваш пример. Где ошибка?

```js
var pointsOfSurface = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8]
];

var objSurface = {
  width: 2,
  height: 2,
  vertices: {}
};

objSurface.vertices = pointsOfSurface;

function getCellsOfSurface(objSurface) {
  var result = [];
  var cell = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    radiation: 0
  };
  var averageRadiation;
  for (var j = 1; j < objSurface.height; j++) {
    for (var i = 1; i < objSurface.width; i++) {
      averageRadiation = objSurface.vertices[2][3];
      cell['x'] = i;
      cell['y'] = j;
      cell.radiation = averageRadiation;
      result.push(cell);
    };
  };
  return result;
};

console.log(getCellsOfSurface(objSurface));
```

Вы, совершенно определенно, вылезаете за границу массива. Ищите. Возможные причины: неправильные значения `width` и `height`, асинхронность.

А по поводу:

> у всех cell.x и cell.y я получаю одно и то же значение

```
  for (var j = ... j++) {
    for (var i = ... i++) {
      averageRadiation = objSurface.vertices[2][3];
      var cell = { // создаем новый объект
        x: i,
        y: j,
        radiation: averageRadiation
      }
      result.push(cell);
    }
  }
```

Comment: благодарю, перепроверил всё и проблему решил, за решение с cell тоже спасибо.